# Bash script to Python no idea how

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I want to convert this script to Python 3.5:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
  while read x; do
    case "$x" in 
      *"boolean true"*) source /home/user/bin/TV-Off.sh;;
      *"boolean false"*) source /home/user/bin/Super-on.sh;;  
    esac
  done
```

Is it even possible?

I found this [converting script online](https://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/index.html) but I cant get it to work. I receive `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

**Update**

I think i may have done it except I cant seem to loop it without high processor usage from the loop I commented out. I also attempted to copy the bash script with no luck, but I feel I'm missing something simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import dbus
#import time

count = 0
#while True:                             <---- First loop try high cpu
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
gnome_screensaver = 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
object_path = '/{0}'.format(gnome_screensaver.replace('.', '/'))
get_object = session_bus.get_object(gnome_screensaver, object_path)
get_interface = dbus.Interface(get_object, gnome_screensaver)
status = bool(get_interface.GetActive())
#    print(status)                      <---- First loop try high cpu
#    if status == True:                 <---- First loop try high cpu
#       print("do something")           <---- First loop try high cpu   
#    if status == False:                <---- First loop try high cpu
#        print("stopping")              <---- First loop try high cpu
#    count += 1                         <---- First loop try high cpu
#    time.sleep(10)                     <---- First loop try high cpu
#    if count >= 500:                   <---- First loop try high cpu
#        break                          <---- First loop try high cpu
x = status    
#while x: <- Second loop try didnt work no output as screen goes black
if status == True:
    print("do something")
if status == False:
    print("stopping")
```

Comment: I mean, you could always use `os.system`, but... :-)

Comment: I will do some research for You. As I see You are trying to get some state from the dbus, in your case this is Gnome ScreenSaver bus. To answer your question : Yes I am 99% sure this will be possible in Python. There are example usages of the dbus in python https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=org.gnome.ScreenSaver&type=Code

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit more searching I've found what I needed on [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631997/subscribe-for-dbus-event-of-screen-power-off) 
So I changed it a bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from gi.repository import GLib
#from Newtest import tvon,  tvoff
import dbus
import logging
#def sccreen():

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

def message_callback(bus, message):
    if message.get_interface() == "org.gnome.ScreenSaver":
        if message.get_member() == "ActiveChanged":
            screensaver_enabled = bool(message.get_args_list()[0])
#            screensaver_enabled = bool(message.get_args_list()[0] and true)
            logger.info("Screen saver changed. Active: %s", screensaver_enabled)
            if screensaver_enabled == True:
                global tvonn
                print("tv off")
                tvonn = False
#                tvoff()
            if screensaver_enabled == False:
                print("tv on")
                tvonn = True
#                tvon()
#            print("oooooo")
#            print(screensaver_enabled)

session = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
session.add_match_string_non_blocking("interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'")
session.add_message_filter(message_callback)
logger.info("Starting up.")

loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```